# What are reasons to name (or not name) ElasticLoadBalancer resources in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudformation

The [AWS CloudFormation (CFN) documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#cfn-ec2-elb-elbname) allows naming of ElasticLoadBalancers (ELB).  If I name an ELB, the following restrictions apply:

> Important
>   If you specify a name, you cannot do updates that require this resource to be replaced. You can still do updates that require no or some interruption. If you must replace the resource, specify a new name.

As I see it, one of the reasons for naming an ELB in CFN would be to prevent accidental replacement of an ELB, which would result in a new CNAME record to be changed. It seems to me, that I always want to name an ELB. Is there additional reasoning or best practices that I should be aware of concerning the naming of ELBs?